# Why does this code only works with && not ||? Using || in place of && the program just goes on forever

Tags: c++

```
int main ()
{
string s;
    while ((s != "Y" && s != "y" && s != "N" && s != "n"))
    {
        cin >> s;
    }
    cout << "thank you!";
 }
```

Why does this not work with "or" instead of "and". It seems to make sense grammatically both ways?

Comment: It doesn't make sense with OR at all. `s` can't be all four of them at the same time.

Comment: Let me ask you, if `s == "n"` what is the result of `(s != "Y" || s != "y" || s != "N" || s != "n")`?

Comment: Take a look at `std::toupper` and `std::tolower`.  Convert your input to lower case or upper case before comparing.

Comment: "It seems to make sense grammatically both ways?" C++ is not English.

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a this example

```
Input -> Y
s != "Y"   --> false
s != "y"   --> true
s != "N"   --> true
s != "n"   --> true
```

As you can see full condition will be always true, regardless of you input

```
false || true || true || true    --> true
```

Comment: lol right!! just got off break, kind of forgot how my logical operators worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OR expression evaluates `true` if **one or both of its oprand is `true`**

Let's say `U` is the universal set of `string` values.

- for expression `s != a`, this evaluates to true if `s` belongs to the complementary set of `{a}` in `U`
- for expression `s != b`, this evaluates to true if `s` belongs to the complementary set of `{b}` in `U`

now we take logic `OR` as set union. What will happen if we combine the two set while `a != b`? We get `U`.

So whatever `s` is, your condition will always evaluate to `true`.

When take logic and as set intersection, you will understand why using `&&` is correct.